# htaccess rewriteRule for url folder

Tags: .htaccess

If I have link in my localhost

```
localhost/github/atol-universitas/backend/admin.php
```

how to write htaccess for this link?

```
localhost/github/atol-universitas/admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/github/atol-universitas/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /github/atol-universitas/

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ backend/admin.php [L,NC]
```